# Why is this code giving runtime error?

Tags: c, runtime, runtime-error

> There will be multiple integers in the input. You have to write a
>   computer program to read each integer and print Even if the integer is
>   divisible by 2, else print Odd. To help further, the number of
>   integers (T) to read will be the first input to the computer program.
>
> Input Format:  First line of input contains count of integers: T. T>=1
>   After that, each line contains the integer N.
>
> Sample Input:
>
> 2 4 5
>
> Sample Output:
>
> Even Odd

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{   
    int i,T,a[10];/*Assuming Number of integers would be less than 10*/
    printf("Enter the Number of integers\n");
    scanf("%d",&T);
    for(i=0;i<T;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",a[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    for(i=0;i<T;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]%2==0)
            printf("Even\n");
        else
            printf("Odd\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if the question is about a runtime error, you should print the error.. if it is a segfault, you should say so.

Comment: Vote to close as simple typo. The standard "forgot & in scanf" mistake.

Comment: scanf("%d",a[i]); -> scanf("%d",&a[i]);

Answer (score 2):

You have `scanf("%d",a[i]);`.  Scanf is looking for a pointer to an integer, and you're passing an integer (which is likely to be 0 since you haven't assigned anything; note also that zero is generally equal to NULL).  You want  `scanf("%d",&a[i]);`.  Also note that your compiler should be giving you a warning about this... if using gcc, you should get in the habit of always compiling code with `-Wall`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone. I found out the error and used dynamic memory
 allocation for the program. This was the program I used. If somebody
 could help me cut down the code to few lines then please help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i,*ptr,t;
    printf("Enter the count:");
    scanf("%d",&t);
    ptr=(int*)malloc(t*sizeof(int));
    if(ptr==NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory not allocated\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    if(t>=1)
    {
        for(i=0;i<t;++i)
        {
            printf("Enter Data:");
            scanf("%d",ptr+i);
        }
        for(i=0;i<t;i++)
        {
            if((*(ptr+i))%2==0)
                printf("%d is Even\n",*(ptr+i));
            else
                printf("%d is Odd\n",*(ptr+i));
        }
    }   
    return 0;   

}
```